# create a new dataframe depending on another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
ID  T1  T2
a   no  no
a   no  yes
a   no  yes
b   no  no
b   yes no
```

If there is a yes for the column for the same ID then I want to write "yes" in another column, if there is never a "yes" for the same ID then I just want a "no" in the new data frame.
So I want to create the following data frame:

```
ID  T1  T2
a   no  yes
b   yes no
```

So far I have this:

```
  for ( i in 1:end){
    sameCol=TRUE
    for (j in 1:end2){
      subID = table[j,1]
      if (table[j,i]=="yes"){
        if (table[j,1]==table[j-1,1]){
          isSAME=TRUE
        }
        isyes=TRUE
      }
      if((isyes==TRUE) & (isSAME==TRUE){
           table2[j,i]="yes"
      } else {
           table2[j,i]="no"
      }
    }
  }
```

But my code unfortunately doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, `for` loops usually have easier alternatives.

With the library `dplyr`, you can summarise the data by group using `group_by` and `summarise`. Here, you want to have `"yes"` in the column if there is at least one `"yes"` in the column, otherwise `"no"`. Use `across` to perform this across multiple columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(T1:T2, ~ ifelse(any(.x == "yes"), "yes", "no")))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  ID    T1    T2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     no    yes  
2 b     yes   no
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%  group_by(ID) %>% summarize_all(max)
```

Output:

```
  ID    T1    T2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     no    yes  
2 b     yes   no
```

Comment: @Mael has a more complete explanation. Note that `summarize_all()` has been superseded by the use of `across()` within the `summarize()` call.  You can still use the `max` shortcut I used here, but the `if_else()` shown in @Mael's answer is more explicit.